# How to resolve an error in Yolov5 train,py in yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yolov5

I am trying to run yolov5 in Google colab GPU free version

`!pip install PyYAML==5.3`

I am getting an error

```py
Model Summary: 407 layers, 8.84875e+07 parameters, 8.84875e+07 gradients
    Optimizer groups: 134 .bias, 142 conv.weight, 131 other
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/content/yolov5/train.py", line 116, in train
       ckpt['model'] = {k: v for k, v in ckpt['model'].float().state_dict().items()
      File "/content/yolov5/train.py", line 117, in <dictcomp>
        if model.state_dict()[k].shape == v.shape}  # to FP32, filter
    KeyError: 'model.18.conv.weight'
```

My command in google colab is

```py
!python /content/yolov5/train.py --img 640 --batch 4 --epochs 30 \
  --data /content/yolov5/data/clothing.yaml
  --cfg /content/yolov5/models/yolov5x.yaml \
  --weights yolov5x.pt \
  --name yolov5_clothing --cache
```

Can you please help me to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved by yolo team asked me to run requirements.txt and download yolo again.

Everything is fine you can see the more details on https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/2181

Thanks